# Get the dates of all the Mondays between two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to return the dates of all the Mondays between two dates. Here is what I've done so far.

```
function populate_week_range_options(){
    var start_week_date = new Date(2012, 7-1, 2); // no queries exist before this
    //console.log(start_week_date);
    var todays_date = new Date();

    // array to hold week commencing dates
    var week_commencing_dates = new Array();
    week_commencing_dates.push(start_week_date);

    while(start_week_date < todays_date){
        var next_date = start_week_date.setDate(start_week_date.getDate() + 1);

        start_week_date = new Date(next_date);
        //console.log(start_week_date);
        if(start_week_date.getDay() == 1){
            week_commencing_dates.push(start_week_date);
        }

       //
    }

    return week_commencing_dates;
}
console.log(populate_week_range_options());
```

Based on the documentation I've read on the getDay() function, it returns an index representing a day of the week (0 to 6, Sunday to Saturday respectively)

However, for some reason my function returns Tuesdays instead - I can't figure out why!

I changed the if statement to compare the day index against 0, and this returns the dates I'm expecting but I'm guessing this the incorrect way to do this as 0 is for Sunday.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Consider using the datejs library https://code.google.com/p/datejs/ they provide some functions you would find useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I wasn't getting the dates I expected because of the way I was pushing elements to the array. I changed my code so that it creates a new variable for every element that is to be pushed to the array. I don't code in JavaScript so don't fully understand this, appreciate it if anyone can explain this behavior. Nonetheless, here is my updated code returning the expected dates:

```
function populate_week_range_options(){
    var start_week_date = new Date(2012, 7-1, 2); // no queries exist before this
    var todays_date = new Date();

    // array to hold week commencing dates
    var week_commencing_dates = new Array();
    var first_monday_date = new Date(2012, 7-1, 2); // no queries exist before this
    week_commencing_dates.push(first_monday_date);

    while(start_week_date < todays_date){
        var next_date = start_week_date.setDate(start_week_date.getDate() + 1);

        var next_days_date = new Date(next_date);
        day_index = next_days_date.getDay();
        if(day_index == 1){
            week_commencing_dates.push(next_days_date);
        }
        // increment the date
        start_week_date = new Date(next_date);
    }

    return week_commencing_dates;
}
```

Comment: Glad that it works now, but this is really odd. I am used to JavaScript and had some odd behaviours in the past, but not like that. As I have tested your code with the same results as you had, I just can say: I don't know the reason why JS behaves like that. Maybe it's a reference issue with the object's method.

Answer (score 1):

getDay() returns the day according to the local timezone. I am assuming that your date is converted from an UTC time to a local time with the offset set up in your computer, which will change the date, and therefore the day of the week. I can't really test this here though.

Edit: I think you should be using getUTCDay() here.

Comment: I don't think this is the case I just did the following: var todays_date = new Date();
console.log(todays_date.getDay()); This returned '3' for Wednesday.

Answer (score 1):

It's really odd, I've tested your code and the funny thing is, it shows me Monday in console.log() when I look inside the if-Block and inside the while-loop (on the LAST added element in the array), but when I look at the end into the full array (so when some milliseconds have passed) all dates are Tuesday. So the day changes after ~1 millisecond. Sorry got no answer for you, but wanted to mention this so anyone else might figure it out.